# X11 Multiple monitors with Putty

Tags: multiple-monitors, putty, x11-forwarding, pycharm

I'm currently trying to use X11 forwarding via Putty on my Windows laptop to run Pycharm. It works fine on my native laptop screen, but when I connect another monitor, I get this:   [White space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF94c.png). 
As you can see, it isn't utilizing the full size of the screen, and in fact important parts are whited out. Note that if I disconnect the other monitor, then everything is fine (screen fully utilized). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks